# How to retrieve missing registry components?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Incident: Installed superantispyware tool, which found/removed an unknown amount of registry components.  After restarting my HPTm2, I had the following major issues:

1) Windows 7 Home Premium switched to Classic Mode and voided any other themes

2) Keyboard shortcuts e.g. brightness and sound no longer worked

3) No network connection capability or even audio control

4) System log is not functioning, thus, no access to errors that may have occurred prior to the deletion.  This also includes System Restore and Creating Images.

Comment: Hi. How can you be sure that it is the program you blame? You make a strong statement, and I understand that you are upset, but there are many possible causes including user error. Also, my main point, what is your question? Regards,

Comment: Well, I wanted to see if there was a way to get those registry parts back.  The laptop is used solely for work i.e. pdf modification programs and the usual e-mail.  Thus, after seeing a how-to-geek on improving Windows 7 performance, I tried to take a stab and pretty much followed by the book with setting task scheduler for disk cleanup, installing this program, and another program that disabled the auto-reboot from those pesky Windows reminders.  There were suggestions for direct registry modifications in the article, but I strayed away.

Comment: Why not just restore a back-up or do a re-installation?

Comment: I agree, although since the Windows 7 was already prepackaged, the only option I have is to restore to factory settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where you can find out what it killed:

After reboot, locate your last log and attach this log to your next message.  We want to see the log even if it is clean.

All logs are stored in the below locations ( where username is the actual user account name that was scanned )

For Windows 2K and XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\SUPERAntiSpyware.com\SUPERAntiSpyware\Logs
```

For VIsta and Windows 7

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\SUPERAntiSpyware.com\SUPERAntiSpyware\Logs
```

You can also rerun SUPERAntiSpyware at anytime and click the View Scan Logs button to view logs and then select any log you wish to view and then click the View Selected Log button to bring the log up in a notepad window. Save this log somewhere you can find it to attach it later. Click the OK button to continue.

Comment: I put in the address for the Logs, but it is telling they don't exist.  I also tried the rerun, but the program cannot be found in the Start Menu.  I tried the F8 System Restore, but it got stuck for 7 hours and I just rebooted my computer.

Comment: I tried to create a system image for backing up files, but I got an error stating "could not start due to an internal error...either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it."